# SQL injection method for select statement

Tags: sql, database, select, code-injection

I want to get same values form my database therefore I'm using this query:

```
SELECT NormalComputers 
FROM usb_compliance 
WHERE ATC = 'CMB' 
ORDER BY date DESC 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Using this I want to get so many values so I plan to use SQL injection method please help me how to create this

If I can use injection method I can use function it should be like this

```
Private Function query(ByVal values As String, ByVal atc As String, ByVal no As Integer)
    Dim connetionString As String
    Dim connection As SqlConnection
    Dim command As SqlCommand
    Dim sql As String
    connetionString = "Server=CTV-WEBDEVEXG;Database=usb;Trusted_Connection=True;"
    sql = "SELECT @values FROM usb_compliance WHERE ATC=@atc ORDER BY date DESC OFFSET @no ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY"
    connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)
    Try
        command = New SqlCommand(sql, connection)
        With command
            .Connection.Open()
            MsgBox("done !!!")
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .Parameters.Add("@values", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = values
            .Parameters.Add("@atc", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = atc
            .Parameters.Add("@NormalComputers", SqlDbType.Int).Value = no
        End With

        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        command.Dispose()
        connection.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
    Return sql
End Function
```

I have tried this way but its not working so please help me on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parameter `@values`  refers to the name of the field you want to retrieve. So it owes to be a string not a `DateTime` (despite the fact that this filed datatype might be `DateTime`).

```
...
.Parameters.Add("@values", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = values
...
```

to get rows affected:

```
Dim numRows as Integer
...
..
numRows=command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: its working but how can i return the sql executed value in the function ?

Comment: can you please let me help to get the  executed value as a integer

Comment: do you want to get the returned field or the number of rows affected by the command?

Comment: my sql query will give a number so i want to get the number as a return value as integer